# store result in the array in c

Tags: c, arrays

In this code i generate numbers of n digits and want to store them in an array 
but when i store them only the last number of the digit is printed from array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int numbergenerator(int N)
{
    for(int number = pow(10, N-1); number < pow(10, N); number++) //find all the n digit numbers
    {
        return number;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    int a[100];
    int N,i;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    for(i=0;i<99;i++)
    {
        a[i]=numbergenerator(N);
    }

    for(i=0;i<99;i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your code. For example, what is the use of calling `numbergenerator(N)` in a loop, when `N` will never change?

Comment: A function stops executing and returns to the caller as soon as a `return` statement is hit. Having `return` in a loop won't magically give you a set of numbers. Instead, it will just return the first number.

Answer (score 1):

Please format your code like following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int numbergenerator(int N){
    for(int number = pow(10, N-1); number < pow(10, N); number++) //find all the n digit numbers{
        return number;
    }
}

int main(){

    int number;
    int a[100];
    int N,i;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    for(i=0;i<99;i++){
        a[i]=numbergenerator(N);
    }

    for(i=0;i<99;i++){
      printf("%d \n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

regarding your question:

```
for(int number = pow(10, N-1); number < pow(10, N); number++) //find all the n digit numbers{
    return number;
}
```

this returns the first number with which you are going into the for loop. so it is returning `pow(10, N-1)`.

you could equally write:

```
int numbergenerator(int N){
    return pow(10, N - 1);
}
```

i guess that's not what you want it to do.
by the way, test what happens if you give 0 or a negative number to your function.

edit:

```
for(i=0;i<99;i++){...}
```

this will iterate from 0 to 98. so the last field of your array will stay at an unitialized value.